# Fetch any managed object with UUID, regardless of type

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Update: I believe this is duplicate of this: [Core Data - Fetch all entities using the same field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47771685/core-data-fetch-all-entities-using-the-same-field)

I want to use a UUID to find all managed objects that have a property with this ID, *regardless of type.*

In the typical case, I would use a fetch request on the entity itself. For example, in a Bookstore I could find a book by a `bookUUID` using a fetch request on `Book`.

```
class BookShelf: NSManagedObject {
    
    @NSManaged var bookUUID: UUID!

    func fetchBook() -> Book? {
        let request = Book.fetchRequest()
        request.sortDescriptors = []
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", "bookUUID", bookUUID as CVarArg)
        return try? self.managedObjectContext?.fetch(request).first
    }
    
}
```

Here this works because `BookShelf` knows about `Book`. But what about the other way around? When a book deletes itself it should find any entities with a property `bookUUID`, regardless of their type.

It could be expressed this way, however this doesn't work. There is no generic `NSManagedObject` entity.

```
extension NSManagedObjectContext {
        
    func findAllObjectsUsingThisBook(bookUUID: UUID) -> Array<NSManagedObject>? {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>()
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %Q", "bookUUID", uuid as CVarArg)
        request.sortDescriptors = []
        return try? self.fetch(request)
    }
    
}
```

Expressed generically, this could be used to find any objects with a certain property.

```
extension NSManagedObjectContext {
        
    func findAllObjectsWithProperty<T>(named propertyName: String, andValue value: T) -> Array<NSManagedObject>? where T: CVarArg {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>()
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %Q", propertyName, value)
        request.sortDescriptors = []
        return try? self.fetch(request)
    }

}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You can’t, you need to search each entity separately. You can of course write a generic function and then call it in a loop for each entity

Comment: You can use subclassing to do that, if I understood correctly your issue. But then, you might need to "cast afterwards" to have the correct subclass if needed.

Comment: Actually this is the purpose of a *Relationship*. The book is being created in **one** entity and can be connected to other entities with a relationship. If you delete the book it will be removed also in the related entities (depending on the settings).

Comment: @ Larme - Correct. In my particular use case I will just delete the objects without checking their type.

Comment: @vadian - Indeed. I am trying to flatten a complex web of relationships.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a parent entity like `BookParent` which has a property `bookUUID`, so you can use it like this `NSFetchRequest<BookParent>()`, you can find more details [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/modeling_data/configuring_entities).

> When a book deletes itself it should find any entities with a property bookUUID, regardless of their type.

From your description, maybe you should create relationships and use [cascade delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124022/how-to-properly-cascade-delete-managed-objects-in-core-data)?